# TypeError: len() of unsized object (SVM: Save prediction scores to csv file)

Tags: python, image-processing, classification, svm

I want to classify a set of images, based on their red histogram values. We have 3 Types of images and the goal is to predict which Type each image belongs to. I am able to save it to a csv that shows which Type the image belongs to, but I also want to show the prediction score, which gives me an error. This is the code:

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import pandas as pd

root = "C:/Users/Ioanna/data/train"
folders = ["Type_1", "Type_2", "Type_3"]
extension = "*.jpg"


def file_is_valid(filename):
    try:
        io.imread(filename)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def compute_red_histogram(root, folders, extension):
    X = [] #2D array : rows=number of images
    y = [] #1D array : numeric class labels (0 for Type_1, 1 for Type_2, 2 for Type_3)
    for n, imtype in enumerate(folders):
        filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, imtype, extension))
        for fn in filter(file_is_valid, filenames):
            print(fn)
            image = io.imread(fn)
            img = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.1, fy=0.1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            red = img[:, :, 0]
            h, _ = np.histogram(red, bins=np.arange(257), normed=True)
            X.append(h)
            y.append(n)
    return np.vstack(X), np.array(y)

X, y = compute_red_histogram(root, folders, extension)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 0)

# train svm classifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_test
clf.predict(X_test)
y_test == clf.predict(X_test)
score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

prediction = pd.DataFrame(y_test, score, columns=['prediction', 'score']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

And I get this: **TypeError: len() of unsized object**
[image]

Comment: Maybe add the full traceback? I imagine this would help those, wanting to help. Thanks.

Comment: how will this be useful? I don't know what you mean exactly

Comment: Ah, ok. For 1) it is the way we read errors from python ourselves every day, for 2) it is easy to just copy and paste in (as easy as formating some extract) and esp. for 3) it has line numbers and possibly details that ring a bell for others, where the submitter of a question may not notice. Maybe I do overlook it, but, I do not spot the place in the above code where "it" exits.

Comment: I updated the question, hope it helps

Comment: Sometimes one says 'a picture is worth a thousand words' and sometimes the other way around (at SO we expect text no bitmap for tracebacks / error info) ;-) So, looking at the bitmap: The first error was a value error (where 2 "things" had been expected, but only 1 provided (this might be the more interesting error, hint, hint) than while handling that ValueError, another one (the one you noted) "happened". Usually it helps, to focus on the initial error of a cascade, and then try again ... all the best